# Second Facebook Like Button Not Rendering In IE

Tags: internet-explorer, facebook-like

I'm loading two Facebook like buttons on the page and keeping one hidden.

Using the edge.create event I am showing the second like button after the first one appears. This works great in all browsers, except IE.

Take a look at it in action here: http://coolkidz.com/join

After you click "Like" (top right corner) a second like button should appear along with a message, inviting you to like the organization's fan page.

Any ideas what might be going on in IE?

**Update**

By the way, this did work earlier in the year. A relatively recent update on Facebook's end seems to have caused the trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, I’m not seeing the second like button in Firefox as well – because the `<span>` element around it and the iframe as well are set to `width:0; height:0;` …

> Any ideas what might be going on in IE?

It think it is problematic in IE to try to render XFBML elements that are currently hidden from the page. Try making the element visible first, and run FB.XFBML.parse on it explicitly afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I don't believe I'm setting any width or height on the span - knowing that you're having trouble seeing it in Firefox is very helpful, though - I will take a closer look.

Also, thanks for the visibility suggestion - I will give that a go!

Comment: I wound up going a different route - setting the width and height of the div to 0 (then to auto) rather than display:none. You tipped me in the right direction, though - so thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, the like button was inside a div that was hidden `display:none;` when the page loaded.

When the Facebook SDK loads it checks what the outer div width/height is and then resizes the Facebook span width/height and the inner iframe width/height to the outer div width/height.

If your div is set to hidden it has a width/height of 0, my solution was to use css `visibility:hidden;`